# Meteor crashes with error: No version 0.9.1 of package iron-router was found

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

Running Meteor 0.8.3, haven't worked on my project since Monday.  Today I can't start Meteor nor use Meteorite package manager:

```
/usr/local/bin/mrt run

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:63
      throw('No version ' + version + ' of package ' + self.name + ' was found
                                                                 ^
No version 0.9.1 of package iron-router was found in the atmosphere database

Process finished with exit code 8
```

I have a sneaky suspicion it has something to do with them prepping the new Meteor package system.  Does anyone know how I might be able to get this app running again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that an upcoming version of iron-router got pushed prematurely. Instructions for rolling back are [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/777#issuecomment-52661268).

Answer (score 4):

open smart.json and change iron-router entry to following.

```
"iron-router": "0.8.2"
```

run `mrt update`

Comment: That is the version that was already listed in my smart.json file.