# Meteorite update saying iron-router version is incorrect

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I am trying to update my packages, but when I run `mrt update` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:63
      throw('No version ' + version + ' of package ' + self.name + ' was found
                                                                 ^
No version 0.9.1 of package iron-router was found in the atmosphere database
```

I've looked around, and Iron Router has apparently had some hiccups lately:

> **Latest Version**: 0.8.2
>
> **IMPORTANT:** Do not install versions 0.9.0 or 0.9.1 from Atmosphere.
>   These versions are intended for the new Meteor packaging system
>   available in Meteor v0.9.0. iron-router 0.9.x was released by mistake
>   to Atmosphere.

Okay, so it makes sense that this is a problem.

However, I checked my iron-router package's `smart.json`, and I manually changed the version number to `"0.8.2"` (it was `"0.8.1"` before) but still the problem persists.

Am I misunderstanding something here? How can I get this to go away so a `mrt update` will run smoothly?

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408835/meteor-meteorite-app-is-not-running-meteor-0-9rc-the-cause)

Answer (score 1):

> Hey folks, super sorry about this. 0.9.x of iron-router wasn't
>   supposed to be released to Atmosphere. It's for the new Meteor
>   packaging system coming in Meteor v0.9.0. I'm really sorry for the
>   hassle. @richsilv's and @LeCoupa's procedures should work well.

```
rm -rf packages/iron-*
rm -rf packages/iron:*
update smart.json
// smart.json
{
  "packages": {
      "iron-router": {
         "version": "0.8.2"
       },
   }
```

[source](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/777#issuecomment-52661268)